# Multi-threaded Java server vs safe publication

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

When you google for *multi-threaded java server*, most of the time you'll get a solution based on a following pattern:

```
public class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable {
  private Socket socket;

  MultiThreadServer(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    while (true) {
      new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(serverSocket.accept())).start();
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    // ...
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
    // ...
  }
}
```

How does that relate to safe publication idioms presented in *Java Concurrency in Practice*?

> To publish an object safely, both the
>   reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to
>   other threads at the same time. A
>   properly constructed object can be
>   safely published by:
>
> - Initializing an object reference from
>     a static initializer.
> - Storing a
>     reference to it into a volatile field.
> - Storing a reference to it into a final
>     field.
> - Storing a reference to it into
>     a field that is properly guarded by a
>     (synchronized) lock.

Is it really safe to use `socket` within `run()` method without any extra synchronization, is it safely published? Please do write more than just *yes* or *no*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe because start of the thread defines a *happens-before* relation. That is, `MultiThreadServer` constructor call *happens-before* execution of the thread's `run` method.

From [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/) 17.4.4-17.4.5:

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread

Precautions from *Java Concurrency in Practice* are applicable in the case when the object is made accessible to other *existing* threads, so they are not applicable to this case.

Comment: This means if the thread was fetched from a thread-pool instead of the new Thread() there, it would not be safe - or am I not getting that correctly ? (in which case marking the `socket` field as final would be sufficient ?)

Comment: @nos: `ExecutorService` offers the same guarantee explicitly in javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html